# How are all the different Vedantic schools viewed by the Shakta sampradaya?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, tantra, shakti, shaktism

Recently I happened to read somewhere that Shaktism more or less rejects Vedanta and accepts only Tantra as the supreme authority, This makes me curious to know how all the different Vedantic philosophies such as Advaita, bhedabheda, Vishishtadvaita, and Advaita are viewed by the Shakta sect.

Comment: There is shrauta shaktism also

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Which kula or subsect comes under shrauta shaktism?

Comment: That I don't know, but there are many learners of veda who are shaktas

Comment: I’m new Shakta convert as of this year and it is def more Tantra side re the Hindu texts I am taught to follow. However I’m very new, there are Shakta folks on HSE who’ve been on the path for years and decades, they can explain much better; hopefully one of them sees this question and gives a reply eventually 

Answer (score 2):

In a book "Sakti and Sakta" Sir John Woodroffe (8th edition, 1975), writes that it is an error to think that Tantra Sastra is not based on Vedanta(Ch.34, p. 234). According to him, every form of Hinduism is based on Veda and Vedanta. He was an authority on Saktatantra and has written several books on this and related topics.